# Movie about a criminal inside a bar

Tags: identify-this-movie, thriller

I have seen this movie three or four years ago, it was indeed catchy and entertaining; and it got stuck in my memory. The very well american produced movie should be released between 2004 and 2009.

I remember that the movie started with a girl doing her job as cashier (or waitress). She seemed very proud of herself that she is pictured at the beginning of the movie recalculating the bill of a person.

Later the villain takes out a gun (and changes the mark of bar's as "closed" on the door) to prevent new customers from coming. The villain threatened the people. I don't remember what was the purpose, but I think he wanted to meet someone in the bar.

There was a lot of shooting in the movie, it was bloody, and I remember that a lot of people got killed; there were one couple hugging each other and scared.

What was bizarre about the movie, is that no cops came, and all the movie happens inside in the shop (yes, there are no scenes outside the shop).

Comment: I think I know this... Were there a lot of twists and a very small cast?

Comment: @Walt, I think yes.

Comment: ...can't remember the name, only images. :( Were there 2 tough women who were possibly a couple? And one of them got shot?

Comment: @Walt, possible, there was definitely a couple and someone got shot. I was trying to remember the ending, I don't think he survives at the end, I think only the cashier (girl) survives.

Comment: OK, brain slow today but I think I figured it out. ;)

Comment: @Walt, you can do it :) I tried searching a lot on google but no results...

Comment: Glad you found it. Oddly enough, I think the film **I** was talking about is different, something very twisty with a couple of female robbers. But it doesn't pique my interest enough to put up a question myself. ;)

Comment: @Walt, is it by chance [Bound (1996)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bound_(film)), what [was](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=a0PZv_VTZhU) on your mind?

Comment: Nah. But it's possible I just mashed up *Bound* with this one in my head, who knows?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I think you're after [The Killing Jar](http://www.imdb.com/title/tt1270296/combined) from 2010 with Michael Madsen, Danny Trejo and Amber Benson:

> A stranger armed with a shotgun takes seven patrons hostage in a remote roadside diner. But as the body count increases, the desperate survivors discover that one of the hostages may be even more dangerous than their captor.

It all takes place in the diner, several people are shot, and you can see in the trailer the scared couple hugging and the killer flipping the sign to "closed":

Comment: Yes, definitely this is it. Thanks. Gonna watch it online.